# Dansguardian - Allowing some user to view some websites

Tags: ldap, ubuntu-10.04, squid, dansguardian

I have configured squid+ldap with dansguardian. Now the requirement is all the users should not get all the websites opened.

Can I configure dansguardian in a such a way that it should allow only some users which have paermision. I have also created filters. but I could not see that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Modify "filtergroups" in dansguardian.conf
2. cp dansguardianf1.conf dansguardianf2.conf
3. You might want to modify "groupname" in each dansguardianfN.conf file just to see your new groups in access.log
4. Modify "exceptionsitelist", "bannedphraselist" etc. in each dansguardianfN.conf

Example:

```
grep filtergroups ./dansguardian.conf
filtergroups = 2

grep "groupname\|exceptionsitelist\|bannedphraselist" ./dansguardianf2.conf
groupname = 'hr'
exceptionsitelist = '/etc/dansguardian/lists/exceptionsitelist_hr'
bannedphraselist = '/etc/dansguardian/lists/bannedphraselist'

cat ./exceptionsetelist_hr
site1.tld.com
site2.tld.com
.Include</etc/dansguardian/lists/exceptionsitelist>
```

All users not explicitly listed in other groups will be routed to filter1 (config: dansguardianf1.conf)

Try this:
http://contentfilter.futuragts.com/wiki/doku.php?id=group_configuration